# My OOP Approach Seems Wrong - Having to Check Class

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I have a piece of equipment I'll be connecting to, and that connection could be over TCP/IP or a serial connection.  I'm writing a class that models the configuration data, and one of the configuration options is information about that connection.

A serial connection has configuration settings like CommPort, BaudRate, Parity, etc.  A TCP/IP connection will have Host and Port.

So it seems obvious that I'm going to have SerialConnectionInfo and TcpConnectionInfo classes.  But those classes are members of an Equipment class.

I seems like there should be some master ConnectionInfo class or interface, but the problem is that while those two classes are conceptually similar, they don't share any common fields.  So something like the following doesn't seem to make any sense:

```
interface IConnectionInfo {
}

class SerialConnectionInfo : IConnectionInfo {
  string CommPort;
}

class TcpConnectionInfo : IConnectionInfo {
  string Host;
}

class Equipment {
  IConnectionInfo Connection;
}
```

I *could* do something like that, but then at some point I'm definitely going to have to check which class Connection is, and cast it to the proper class.  It all smells wrong.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: It depends how and where you are going to use these config settings - you could add a `Configure()` method to `IConnectionInfo` so that `TcpConnectionInfo` can use its own internal settings it knows about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the interface where you're not interested in the implementation. So the interface should provide a `Connect()` method, which is implemented by the classes.

The classes then contain properties required for that specific connection type. Like this `TcpConnection`:

```
public interface IConnection
{
    void Connect();
}

public class TcpConnection : IConnection
{
    public string Host { get; private set; }
    public int Port { get; private set; }

    private Socket _socket;

    public TcpConnection(string host, int port)
    {
        Host = host;
        Port = port;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        _socket = new Socket(...);
    }
}
```

You can then instantiate it:

```
IConnection connectionInfo = new TcpConnection("example.com", "1337");
```

And pass it around as an interface, calling `Connect()` on it to connect.

Your question does not contain enough info on what exactly the classes, interface or properties should do, so I can't really model my answer to that. Furthermore this looks more like something for http://programmers.stackexchange.com as it is about design as opposed to implementation.

Comment: Thank you.  I had gone down that route, but then I had originally planned to use this class purely as an object model, and was going to have other classes that set up connections and such.  Maybe this *is* the best way to do it.

Comment: If you just want a dumb class to contain connection type specific properties, then I don't think you can put a shared interface on that, because they ... don't share properties (like you found out).

Comment: This approach decouples the *how* from the *what*.  You can still use the socket and serial connection classes as "dumb" data containers *for any code that needs to be aware of their internal structure*.  But the client / consuming code should **not** need to know about those internals -- if it does you're violating the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Unless `TcpConnectionInfo` and `SerialConnectionInfo` have something in common, it doesn't make much sense. If they do however, it would be more sensible, for example:

```
interface IConnectionInfo {
    public string GetConnectionSocketDescription();
    public void Connect();
    // etc
}

class SerialConnectionInfo : IConnectionInfo {
  string CommPort;
  // make GetConnectionSocketDescription return CommPort
  // make Connect work for serial connection
}

class TcpConnectionInfo : IConnectionInfo {
  string Host;
  // make GetConnectionSocketDescription return Host
  // make Connect work for TCP connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Adapter pattern and keep open the option for the client to connect to server either using TCP or Serialport.